# Any issue rebasing commits between feature branches before they are merged back to develop

Tags: git, unit-testing, branch, git-merge, git-rebase

I am working on adding unit tests to a project which is simple enough, but then I find a bug in the code that I am writing unit tests for.

The bug is fairly simple and only involves a single line (Ternary statement was reversed). So like a good little dev, I open a ticket, fix the bug on a bugfix branch and open a pull request to merge the bugfix to develop.

I switched back to my feature branch that I on for my unit tests and of course my unit tests that failed because of the bug are still failing because the bugfix was in its own branch and is awaiting merging with the open Pull Request.

I would like to resume my unit test work as quickly as possible with as little issue as possible and avoid merge conflicts when I have to open my Pull Request with the unit test feature branch.

My question is what is the best way to do this.

I see the following possibilities.

(Prefered but not sure if this would cause merge issues in future)
Rebase the bugfix branch into my feature branch, and when develop is updated and I merge my feature branch since they are the some commit hash it should blend with no issues.

(seems like it would work but also seems like a hassle and easy to mess up if done wrong)
Fix code in my feature branch as well so that I can continue my unit tests, but when I commit all my unit tests do not commit the code from the bug fix. When the Pull Request is approved for my unit tests I would need to make sure the bug fix branch his merged first as my feature branch would break the build for the failed unit tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rebase your `feature branch` against the `bug fix branch` so that your work is "on top of" the bug fix.

This does mean, however, that your feature work adding unit tests can not merge until the bug fix PR is approved and ready to merge as well.

If your `feature branch` got merged first; it would automatically bring your bug fix with it, whether it was approved to merge or not.

If your `bug fix branch` got merged first; when the `feature branch` is merged it would already have the bug fix commit in master and the change would not be applied again.

A lot of "what is best" depends on how your organization handles pull requests, merging, and dependencies between work.

Comment: the bugfix was merged late yesterday and I opened the new Pull Request for my unit tests today and it worked just as you said flawlessly.
Thanks Again.